# How to enable TLS 1.2 in apache?

Tags: apache2, openssl, tls

The current enabled TLS on my server is "tls 1", how can i enable tls 1.2 on my ubuntu server, and do i have to upgrade my openssl first?

```
# apache2ctl -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.12 (Ubuntu)

# openssl version -a
OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007
built on: Fri Dec  3 23:05:00 UTC 2010
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(ptr,char) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(ptr2) 
compiler: gcc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -O3 -Wa,--noexecstack -g -Wall -DMD32_REG_T=int -DMD5_ASM
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to use TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 for SSLProtocol, you need at least version 2.2.23 (in addition to OpenSSL 1.0.1 or higher).

Once you have the latest,

Add

```
SSLProtocol TLSv1.1
```

to

/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

Answer (score 2):

First step is, you will have to upgrade your OpenSSL version to 1.0.1 or higher. Your current OpenSSL version does not support TLS 1.2.

Comment: Upgrading the OpenSSL will it affect the existing ssl certificates installed on the server?, and do i have to upgrade the apache?

Comment: @user225844 no it should not affect existing certificates but instead of upgrading just one package from an unkown source or building it yourself, you should evaluate upgrading to the latest LTS release.